# django: nginx: HTTP_HOST does not show port number

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have the following code running in production

The Nginx config is as follows:

```
# first we declare our upstream server, which is our Gunicorn application
upstream hello_server {
    # docker will automatically resolve this to the correct address
    # because we use the same name as the service: "djangoapp"
    server webapp:8888;
}

# now we declare our main server

server {

    listen 8558;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # everything is passed to Gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://hello_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Nginx server has port forwarding: `8555:8558`

And the gunicorn command running is

```
gunicorn --bind :8888 basic_django.wsgi:application
```

Now in my browser i open this url:

`http://127.0.0.1:8555/login_register_password/user_login_via_otp_form_email`

Now my code in one of my views is

```
prev_url = request.META['HTTP_REFERER']
# EG: prev_url = http://127.0.0.1:8555/login_register_password/user_login_via_otp_form_email

# we want to get the url from namespace . We use reverse. But this give relative url not the full url with domain
login_form_email_url_reverse = reverse("login_register_password_namespace:user_login_via_otp_form_email")
# EG: login_form_email_url_reverse = "/login_register_password/user_login_via_otp_form_email"

# to get the full url we have to use do the below
login_form_email_url_reverse_full = request.build_absolute_uri(login_form_email_url_reverse)
# EG: login_form_email_url_reverse_full = "http://127.0.0.1/login_register_password/user_login_via_otp_form_email"
```

I am execpting `prev_url` and `login_form_email_url_reverse_full` to be same but it differs

`prev_url` domain is `http://127.0.0.1:8555` whereas `login_form_email_url_reverse_full` domain is `http://127.0.0.1`

why this is happening.

This does not happen in development server. using `runserver`

```
"HTTP_HOST": "127.0.0.1:8555",
"HTTP_REFERER": "http://127.0.0.1:8555/login_register_password/user_login_via_otp_form_email",
```

Where as with nginx server: `HTTP_HOST` changes i.e now without port number

```
"HTTP_HOST": "127.0.0.1",
"HTTP_REFERER": "http://127.0.0.1:8555/login_register_password/user_login_via_otp_form_email",
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by changing

```
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

To

```
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

in the `server {}` of `local.conf` of `nginx`

Got the answer from https://serverfault.com/a/916736/565479